# click not working for observable array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and trying to build a simple application in which I can add data row dynamically but I don't understand why `data-bind="click: remove" in remove button` is not working when I remove `data-bind="click: remove" from remove button` my application will work fine,

How can I remove dynamic element using that remove button?

```js
function people(name) {
    return {
        name: ko.observable(name),
        remove: function () {
            viewModal.peoples.remove(this);
        }
    };
}
var viewModal = {
    self: this,
    firstName: ko.observable(),
    peoples: ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Franklin' },
        { name: 'Mario' },

    ]),
    addMore: function () {
        this.peoples.push(new people(this.firstName()));
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:firstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Add People" data-bind="click:addMore" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: peoples">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <label data-bind="text:name"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="remove" data-bind="click: remove" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As [@GKB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141351/gkb) pointed out in the comments, the main error was the initial people objects lacking a `remove` method, which I turned out to have fixed along the way without really pointing this out in my answer...

**Original answer:**

You can't use `this` like you've tried to.

Either work with plain objects or with `new` class instances:

**Working example:**

```js
// Example 1: using plain objects
function Person(name, app) {
  const self = {
    name: ko.observable(name),
    remove: () => app.people.remove(self)
  };
  
  return self;
}

// Example 2: using `new`
var App = function() {
  const self = this;
    
  this.firstName = ko.observable(),
  this.people = ko.observableArray(
    [ "Franklin", "Mario" ].map(
      name => Person(name, self)
    )
  );
};

App.prototype.addPerson = function() {
  this.people.push(Person(this.firstName(), this));
  this.firstName("");
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Add People" data-bind="click: addPerson" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: people">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <label data-bind="text:name"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="textInput: name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="remove" data-bind="click: remove" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In fact, `this` works the way OP has used. The issue is with the `peoples` observable array not holding instances of `people` objects. Instead they have anonymous objects that don't have the `remove` function defined on them...fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lhjytgn8/

Comment: Oops.. I was too triggered by the `this` usage that I only accidentally fixed the actual error... Would you like to post it as an answer, or shall I edit mine?

Comment: oh `[ "Franklin", "Mario" ].map(` this is where i am making mistake right ?

Comment: Yes, as @gkb rightfully pointed out, the only "real" error was that you forgot to cast your initial people to `Person` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much @gkb